# Prove that $n^{n+1} \leq (n+1)^{n} \sqrt[n]{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, factorial

Let $n$ be a positive integer. I conjectured that the following inequality is true
\begin{equation}
n^{n+1} \leq (n+1)^{n} \sqrt[n]{n!} .
\end{equation}
Anyhow I could neither prove nor disprove it. I could only check, by using Stirling's Formula, that the ratio of the right and left members tends to 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n}\right)
&=\log(n)-n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\
&=\log(n)+n\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\
&\le\log(n)-\frac{n}{n+1}\\
&\le\log(n)-\frac{n-1}n\\
&=\frac1n\int_1^n\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\frac1n\sum_{k=2}^n\log(k)\\
&=\log\left(\sqrt[n]{n!}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Exponentiate and rearrange to get
$$
n^{n+1}\le(n+1)^n\sqrt[n]{n!}
$$

Answer (score 22):

Taking logarithms the inequality is equivalent to
$$
(n+1)\log n\le n\log(n+1)+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log k.
$$
We estimate now the sum:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\ge\int_1^n\log x\,dx=n\log n-n+1.
$$
It will be enough to prove that
$$
n\log n\le n\log(n+1)-1+\frac1n,
$$
or equivalently
$$
1-\frac1n\le n\log\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr).
$$
This follows from the inequality $\log(1+x)\ge x-x^2/2$, $0<x<1$.

Comment: A very elegant proof. I could never have found it by myself! Thank you very much, Julian.

Answer (score 6):

From $$
e^{-1} = \left(e^{-\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)^{n+1} > \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}(\because e^x \ge x+1)
$$

and

$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} = 1
$$

Note

$$e \le (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}=\frac{(1+n)^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}} \Leftrightarrow n^{n+1} \le \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e} $$

Also note
$$n!e^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{n^k\frac{n!}{k!}} \ge \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n^k\frac{n!}{k!}} \ge \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n^k\binom{n}{k}}= ({n+1})^n \Leftrightarrow \sqrt[n]{n!} \ge \frac{n+1}{e} $$

This gives us that $$(n+1)^{n} \sqrt[n]{n!} \ge \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e} \ge n^{n+1}$$.

Comment: Graphically, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n!-(%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7Be%7D)%5En, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e-(1%2B1%2Fn)%5En,  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e-(1%2B1%2Fn)%5E(n%2B1)

Comment: To prove the second inequality, note that $n! e^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{k!} n^{k} > \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!} n^{k} > \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} n^{k} = (n+1)^n$. Now by using the two inequalities quoted in the answer we get: $n^{n+1} < (n+1)^{n+1} / e = (n+1)^{n} (n+1)/e < (n+1)^{n} \sqrt[n]{n!}$. Great proof! Thank you very much.

Comment: @MauryBarbato Thank you for your kind complements!

Comment: Fixed small typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel inclined to do "nice" (erm) calculus, you can always choose to study one of these two functions:
$$
f\colon x\in [1,\infty) \mapsto \Gamma(x+1) (x+1)^{x^2} - x^{x^2+x}
$$
or
$$
g\colon x\in [1,\infty) \mapsto \frac{\Gamma(x+1) (x+1)^{x^2}}{x^{x^2+x}}
$$
and show respectively that $f\geq 0$ or $g \leq 1$ on their domain. (for instance, as $g$ is increasing, if I'm not mistaken, so after showing this you would only have to compute $\lim_\infty g$).

This will not be very enjoyable, but should work: whichever of the two functions you choose, it'll be differentiable and nicely behaved. (If you want, you can even define them on $[2,\infty)$ instead if technicalities at $1$ pop up.)

Comment: Clement C., are my statements true/helpful? I'm not experienced so I am not sure...

Comment: Regarding my answer: the idea being "if it's true on $\mathbb{R}$ (or here on $[1,\infty)$), then it'll be true on $\mathbb{N}$." But on the reals, one has all the machinery of real analysis and calculus to draw upon...

Comment: @Clement C. Apart from the fact that the $2x$ should be replaced by $x^2$ in the definitions of $f$ and $g$, I don't see how to prove that $f \geq 0$ or $g \geq 1$. These two functions seem quite complicated to study. By the way, what does it mean "erm"?

Comment: @MauryBarbato Thanks for catching that -- fixed. "Erm" means that the "nice" was sarcastic: this is a systematic method, but not the most elegant and systematic one. As for the functions: they may be complicated to study, but at the end of the day brute-force and differentiation should lead to the proof -- it'll just be a bit painful.

Comment: @Clement C. Why technicalities should pop up at 1? I know very little about the game function, and it seems to me quite cumbersome to deal with it and its derivatives.

Comment: Eyeballing the expression, you have a term $x^{x^2+x} = e^{(x^2+x)\ln x}$. At some point I thought that this may bring in some of these "technicalities" because of the $\ln x$, but actually it should not (I mistook $\ln 1$ and $\ln 0$ somehow).